# How do you join two fields in one table into a second table?

Tags: mysql, lamp

I have a table which contains three fields two of which link into the same table to lookup the value (the third links to a second table)

```
Deployment Table
---------------------------------
INDEX,  APP,  DEVSERVER, PRODSERVER (was previously just SERVER)

Server Table
---------------------------------
INDEX, NAME

App Table
---------------------------------
INDEX, NAME
```

Previously, when I had just *SERVER* in the deployment table I was doing:

```
SELECT d.index, a.name as `app`, s.name as `server`
FROM deployment as `d`, app as `a`, server as `s`
WHERE d.app = a.index AND d.server = s.index
```

and it was working fine.  But now that I want to "double dip" into the server table with *DEVSERVER* and *PRODSERVER* I've not the foggiest way how to go about it.

Comment: It is not very clear, actually.Do you want to retrieve `DEVSERVER` and `PRODSERVER` too or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use proper `join` syntax.  Second, you need to introduce a second join to the `server` table:

```
SELECT d.index, a.name as app, dserv.name as devserver, pserv.name as prodserver
FROM deployment d join
     app a
     on d.app = a.index join
     server dserv
     on d.devserver = dserv.index join
     server pserv
     on d.prodserver = pserv.index;
```

Comment: Nailed it... slight tweak in the pserv.index (rather than .serv)  **SELECT d.index, a.name as app, dserv.name as devserver, pserv.name as prodserver
FROM deployment d 
JOIN app a on d.app = a.index 
JOIN server dserv on d.devserver = dserv.index 
JOIN server pserv on d.prodserver = pserv.index**